# “Fatal error: No screens found.” on Toshiba laptop running 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 with Intel graphics card

Tags: xorg

I’m taking care of two systems featuring dual installs of Windows and 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. However, one of these systems crashed with the message

> Fatal error: No screens found.

This system is a **Toshiba Satellite C55-B5101** laptop, with an Intel Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series graphics card. The desktop displays folders with Libre Office files I can open, but the launcher does not display apps. I can boot up in failsafe graphic mode, but that doesn’t fix the problem permanently, i.e., the same problem recurs if I’m not in failsafe mode. The system had been working just fine for a year.

I’ve searched for similar problems in forums, and found a few. In one of them, someone had the same message.

> No screens found

In that case, it was a corrupted **xorg** config file. Fixing the problem might involve editing the config file, adding the proper section for screens, but I’m not sure where to find the right config file. I think it should be in ext/x11, but I only see `xorg.conf.failsafe`, not `xorg.conf`. Otherwise, might the config file be in `usr/share/x11/config.d`? I’m not sure which of the nine files in there might be the right one.

I’ve also tried generating a config file by running X -configure, but get the message:

> Fatal server error;
>   Server is already active for display 0; if this server is no longer
>   running, remove /tmp/.x0-lock and start again

Well, I have no such file in tmp. Would anyone have some clues for me? Hopefully, I can get assistance specific to my system, and hopefully, I just need to create or edit a config file, rather than get a new driver.

Thanks!

**Status on April 15:** Okay guys, I’ve learned a few things since posting, though I don’t yet have a solution.

For one thing, it appears that 16.04 uses `xorg.conf.failsafe` as its config file, rather than `xorg.conf.` I think this is the case because my healthy system has no `xorg.conf` file in `etc/x11.`

For another, the log file (`xorg.failsafe.log`) states that the config file lacks a Layout section. I’m still not sure whether I should try manually adding such a section. I’d like to find a pattern to follow.

As mentioned above, I’ve also tried generating a config file, which would adapt to system hardware. (This sounds ideal.) Could someone tell me whether I’m using the right command for this? I’ve tried variations, such as the following.

> X --configure
>
> Xorg -configure

I tried these with and without prefacing the command with sudo, but in all of these cases got the message

> Command not found

Any hints for solving my problem?